# Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never' when assigning to object's property

Tags: typescript

TypeScript compiler gives me `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'never'` error for the `data[key] = 2;` assignment in the code snippet below even though I explicitly check the type before the assignment ([see on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAJgQygmBeGBvAUDGCBcMAjADQ4wBGhA5BdWQL4DcWWAFAPIUBWApsFAB0Aa14BPCG0TIAlHggwAggCdlCMQB5RYkADMYUMQAdee+EgQA+GYN0hlAUQTAAFmzba5qS5nIBLfTZDEzNpBABtbQBdNFR0ajAAVwBbCl5lajkwyPEY9AAmFgYZFiA)).

What is causing the error and what would be a proper way to manipulate all number properties of an object?

```
const data = {
  a: 1,
  b: 'b',
};

(Object.keys(data) as Array<keyof typeof data>).forEach((key) => {
  if (typeof data[key] === 'number') data[key] = 2;
});
```